# Android Exiting AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, break

I have an AsyncTask running a loop which only stops looping when exiting the app, a global "stop" boolean gets set and it stops the loop and finishes through the AsyncTask.

I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
     KillAllThreads(); 
}

@Override 
public void onUserLeaveHint() 
{     
    KillAllThreads();       
}
```

Now here is the thing.  If I initiate the AsyncTask, onUserLeaveHint() gets called right away, and when the home button is pressed, it never fires this method.  If I dont initiate the AsyncTask and let the activity load without doing anything, then when I press Home, it fires the onUserLeaveHint() method.

How am I supposed to stop the thread if the user clicks out of the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call .cancel() on a AsyncTask, have you tried that?

Have a look at this sample project on my google docs, It illustrates the important aspects of AsyncTask:

- starting a task, publishing progress, etc.
- It shows how to cancel the running task.
- It shows how to cancel a running task when your activity is paused or stopped.

link:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BwAnjRVwT4WzOWMwYjFhNTctOTUxYy00NjQwLTgwNWEtMmE5MzEyZWQ3NjUx&hl=en_US&authkey=CLnH8_ID

Comment: Call .cancel from where?  I also tried calling myTask.cancel(true) in onStop() and it just crashes.

Comment: Try calling cancel(false) the false means the in-progress tasks are allowed to complete, calling this guarantees that onPostExecute(...) is never invoked. You should check the value returned by isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(...) to finish the task. Basically when you call cancel, it means isCancelled() is true, so add the line "if (isCancelled ()) break;" into your doInBackground() method.

Comment: tried it in onStop, myTask.cancel(false);  crashes right away

Comment: i've added a link to an example project i've got, should help you out.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Thanks Kenny, after looking at the code, I noticed you make a call to the super class, which is described in the Android documentation.  The call to super.onStop() within the onStop method is necessary or it crashes.  So I call super.onStop() followed by my stop code.